# Big O analysis trying to follow a logic

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

Can someone please help me understand why(the derivation) "**and m = 2n+1 for each n.**"?
I am trying to follow the logic of the solution provide while myself have a different approach. Here is my thinking (questions state below):

The inner for loop runs m times from 1 and the outer for loop runs n times from 1.  Moreover, for each inner loop, m is increased by 2 based on previously additions and m starts at 1. With all these
observations, plug in n = 1, print (j) get executed 3 times; n = 2, print(j) get executed 8 times. n = 3,print(j) get executed 15 times.  We calculate the sequence to be 3,8, 15.....  which has the closed form as 2 n +$ n^ 2$ . Or by asymptotic run time as Θ( $n^2$ )

```
  fun(n) 
       m = 1 
       for i = 1 to n 
          m = m + 2 
          for j = 1 to m 
             Print(j)
```

Solution: The  assignment  m=1  takes  constant  time.  The  line  m  =  m  +  2  is  run  n  many  times,  which
takes Θ( n ) time.  The inner print statement runs m many times, **and m = 2n + 1 for each n**.  The total number of times the print statement runs is 
 [image]
Can someone please help me understand why(the derivation) "**and m = 2n+1 for each n.**"? How can we draw the connections with "the line m = m+2 is run m many times.." and "the inner print statement runs m many times" to get "and m = 2n+1 for each n."?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I just realized, i have to click the check mark to consider accepted an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am pleased to see that you have grown your reputation as well as maintain a positive question record. Also the scholar badge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly it's not for each $n$, but for each $i$.

First, try to calculate $m$ for each specific $i$:

```
 i | m
-------
 1 | 3
 2 | 5
 3 | 7
 4 | 9
   :
 n | 2n+1
```

$m$ increased by two for each loop of `for i = 1 to n`. Therefore $m = 2i+1$ for each $i$ in the loop.

And this is repeated from $i = 1$ to $i = n$, so in total,

$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n (2i + 1) = n^2 + 2n
$$